# Ruby regex: Capturing dot with new lines conditionally followed by another expression

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a multi-line string where I need to capture an expression that includes newlines, but only up to another expression that may or may not be there.

A sample string:

```
FOO
Hello
world
BAR
Hello
```

Here I want to capture "Hello world" (including new lines), which I can do with

```
/FOO(.*)BAR/m
```

But `BAR` may or may not be in the string. So I I'm inclined to make `BAR` a non-capturing group that may not be there with `?`, as with:

```
/FOO(.*)(?:BAR)?/m
```

But this captures the trailing `BAR` and `Hello`. Other attempts included specifying the `m` mode only for the dot as with

```
/FOO(?m:(.*))(?:BAR)?/
```

but this presents the same problem.

For those graciously helping me you can use http://rubular.com/ for testing regex in Ruby. Thank you!

Comment: Use capture group 1, it doesn't contain `FOO` and `BAR`

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, I'm only working with a single capturing group. E.g. the `(?:something)` is a non-capturing group. This may differ from other regex flavours

Comment: *I need to capture an expression that includes newlines, but only up to another expression that may or may not be there* -- Of course that makes no sense: you can't capture an expression *up to* something that isn't there.

Comment: @7stud Hmm I think the point was that it _might_ be there. I'm working with dynamic content so I can't make assumptions. Mariano's solution appears to work for this scenario.

Comment: @MusikAnimal, My point was that to fully describe what you want, you actually have to state what you want to happen when the *ending word* isn't there!!

Comment: If your string began `"FOOD\nHello\n..."` would you want to match `"D\nHello\nWorld\n"`? If not, you may wish to include a word break `\b` immediately before and after `"FOO"` in your regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option 1 - Negative Lookahead

Make the `.*` match anything except `BAR`. The expression:

```
(?:(?!BAR).)*
```

uses a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to create a *kind of loop* checking, before matching each character, that it's not followed by `BAR`

**Regex**

```
/FOO((?:(?!BAR).)*)/m
```

<kbd>[rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/9x6PYN5iQp)</kbd>

---

#### Option 2 - Lazy quantifier

You can also make `.*` match as few as possible with a [lazy quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) `.*?` (notice the extra `?`). And require the expression to match either `BAR` or `\z` the end of string.

**Regex**

```
/FOO(.*?)(?:BAR|\z)/m
```

<kbd>[rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/crM52NthC1)</kbd>

Comment: That appears to do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> `$'` The string following whatever was matched by the last successful
>   pattern match

```
strs = [
  "",
  "FOO\nHello\nworld\nBAR\nHello",
  "FOOxxxBAR...FOOyyyBAR",
  "FOO\nHello\nworld\nHello",
  "FOOxxxxxxxFOOyyyBAR",
]

strs.each do |str|
  str.scan('FOO') do 
    p $'.split('BAR').first if $'
  end
end

--output:--
"xxx"
"yyy"
"\nHello\nworld\nHello"
"xxxxxxxFOOyyy"
"yyy"
```

Comment: The usage of the cryptic global variable is quite interesting! I did not know about those. Mariano's solution works in my case, but this is still helpful. Thank you for your time.

Comment: *cryptic global variable*--Unfortunately, Matz incorporated too much of perl in ruby.  If you `require 'english'`, then you can spell `$'` as `$POSTMATCH`.